# Using a backing variable for getters and setters

Tags: c#, .net

Perhaps this is a silly question, however, I am resonable new to C# (more from a Java background) and have got confused between different examples I have seen regarding getters and setters of a property.

In some situations the code looks like this:

```
    private string _something;
    public string Something
    {
        get { return _something; }
        set { _something = value; }
    }
```

However, in other examples they do not use this backing member and so it is more like this:

```
    public string Something { get; set; }
```

I do not really see the benefit of using these backing variables (`_something`) unless of course you have some complex logic regarding the setting of the variables.

I am writing my program using the latter approach, but wanted to check I have not missed anything.

Can someone please explain simply why people chose to do the former?  Is it more 'good practice'?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess latter one is prototype definition, like `interface` in java.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Nope.  It's the same - but the backing field is implemented for you by the C# compiler.

Comment: Ah no, I am wrong. This is new syntax having backing variable implicit.

Comment: @Reed yes I thought orthodox.

Comment: The sense is like in Java: you can override simple getter or setter logic in subclass. If you would have just `Something` member, you would unable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I do not really see the benefit of using these backing variables (_something) unless of course you have some complex logic regarding the setting of the variables.

There is no advantage if you're not using it.  With the second approach, there is still a backing variable, but you're letting the compiler do the work of adding it.  As of .NET 3.5 and later, your current approach is perfectly valid.

Of course, as soon as you need to introduce extra logic, then managing the backing store yourself becomes critical.

Comment: So is there more overhead with having the compiler do the work of adding it?

Comment: @AngelBrighteyes No - it's exactly the same as if you write it yourself.  It's just less typing.  (and a different, compiler generated field name)

Comment: @AngelBrighteyes - This is just an example of what is called "syntactic sugar". Shorter code, but operates exactly the same way behind the scene.

Answer (score 6):

The former syntax was necessary prior to .NET 3.5 and is therefore found in older code.

It is functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

One good reason to use the first syntax is for use with MVVM architectures where your properties are bound to front end elements.

Something like:

```
    private string _something;
    public string Something
    {
        get { return _something; }
        set { 
              _something = value; 
              OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Something");
            }
    }
```

That would alert your front end that its bound property has been changed and it has to update.

Comment: Ah, this maybe exactly what I have been seeing.  I am attempting to build my application using the MVVC architecture so have used plenty of tutorials to get to grips with it.  I suspect this is where my confusion has stemmed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

public string Something { get; set; }
is just short hand. in the background it is doing the exact same thing as above.

Answer (score 0):

seconde approach is [Auto-Implement Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing automatic properties from within your instance is the same as declaring a public field, which breaks the [Encapsulation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Therefore, use automatic properties if you don't access them within the same class.  Otherwise, use a member (backing) field and reference that from your local methods while exposing them through a normal .NET property.

Automatic properties were added with .NET 3.0 as syntactical sugar so you no longer need backing fields that aren't referenced within your class.